# d3.js - adjust the selected brush to the left and right corodintates of rectangles

Tags: d3.js

I am brushing over a set of rectangles(series of rectangles). What i need to do is once brushed i would like to select the start and end of the rectangles irrespective of whether it is selected partially. The whole set of rectangles needs to be selected where the brush is drawn.
Currently i am able to brush only once and not further if i execute the code below.
The height of the rectangles are 15. What am i missing here?

I have found that only when i add the following, i am not able to brush again:
gbrush
.attr("x",baseval)
.attr("width",endval);

My code:

```
var baseval, endval,selected,gbrush
//initial brush drawn
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
            .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([30, 290]))
            .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height-50]))
            .on("brushstart", brushstart)
            .on("brush", brush)
            .on("brushend", brushed);

            gbrush=svg.append("g").call(brush);


            function brushed() 
            {
                var e = brush.extent(); 
                //get all the selected rectangles where brushed.
                selected = svg.selectAll("rect").filter(function(d) 
                {
                return d.x_axis <= e[1][0] && d.x_axis + d.width >= e[0][0] && d.y_axis <= e[1][1] && d.y_axis + d.height >= e[0][1];
                })
                gbrush.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("height",  15)
                .attr("y",10)
                //get the start and end point of the rectangle's x-axis where the brush is drawn
                baseval = selected[0][0].x.baseVal.value;
                endval = selected[0][selected[0].length-1].x.baseVal.value;


                gbrush.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("height",  15)
                .attr("y",10)
                .attr("x",baseval)
                .attr("width",endval);

                .....



            }


            function brushstart() 
            {
                //var e = brush.extent(); 
                //brush.extent = [100,100];
                gbrush.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("height",  15)
                .attr("y",10);

            }
            function brush() 
            {
                gbrush.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("height",  15)
                .attr("y",10);
            }
```

Comment: Is my format of the query not valid? I am not sure why i am not getting any comments on this.